# Is there anyway to view line numbers on sass fiiles in visual studio?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, sass, line-numbers

I installed web workbench and started playing around with sass inside visual studio but I can't figure out how to have visual studio show line number on these scss files.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable "Line Numbers" for Plain Text files in Options > Text Editor:

[image]

The text editor will then display line numbers:

[image]

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 or higher, you need to go to `Options > Text Editor > SCSS` instead of `Plain Text`